# MySQL ignore LD_PRELOAD

Tags: systemd, mysql

I trying to use jemalloc with MySQL. I found that I should add enviroment variable LD_PRELOAD to SystemD unit and thats all.

But `lsof /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2` shows nothing. I also tryed to start MySQL from cli with LD_PRELOAD, but still no success.

Tested on Debian 12 and Ubuntu 22.04 with MySQL 8.0.34. What I doing wrong?

Comment: You're probably applying `LD_PRELOAD` to a wrapper script, not the actual binary. Do `file $(type -p mysql)`. Are you testing the client (`mysql`) or the database server daemon (`mysqld`)? You must have a working database server for the client to connect to.

Comment: @waltinator
I added `Environment='LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2'` to mysql server systemd unit. And mysqld process has LD_PRELOAD variable in `/proc/*/environ`. But `lsof` doesn't show processes uses jemalloc.
Also I tried to run `sudo -u mysql LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2 mysqld`. And again, proccess has LD_PRELOAD, but `lsof` shows nothing.

Comment: please use proper syntax formatting

Comment: Read `man ld.so`. It explains `LD_PRELOAD` and its exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, my mistake was that I used `lsof` without `sudo`. Now I tried `sudo lsof /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjemalloc.so.2` and found that actually mysqld is use jemalloc library.
But for some reason `sudo lsof <libpath>` doesn't show processes on Debian, but if I use `sudo lsof -p <pid>`, I see that process is using a preloaded library.